# swift generics and protocol associated type

Tags: swift, generics

I want to know if the following codes are the same or different, if they are different please explain how.

the first one question is a function that accepts a parameter of type class Receiver

```
func genericFunc<T: Receiver>(input: T){
// code
}
```

VS

```
func genericFunc(input: Receiver){
// code
}
```

are they the same or different?

This second question is a protocol that has an Associatedtype

```
protocol TheProtocol{

associatedtype myType
var anyProperty: myType { get set }

 }

func genericFunc<T: TheProtocol>(input: T){
// code
}
```

VS

```
protocol TheProtocol{

associatedtype myType
var anyProperty: myType { get set }

 }

func genericFunc(input: TheProtocol){
// code
}
```

Comment: At the very last(`func genericFunc(input: TheProtocol){`), compiler should be telling you the reason why these declarations are different for compiler.

Answer (score 1):

```
func genericFunc<T: Receiver>(input: T)
```

This is a generic function that takes a specific, concrete type that conforms to a protocol, `Receiver`. If you call `genericFunc` with different types, the compiler will generate a specialized copy of `genericFunc` for each type you call it with. (There can be optimizations that remove some of those copies, but this is how it works conceptually.)

```
func genericFunc(input: Receiver)
```

This is a non-generic function that requires a parameter of the "Receiver existential" type. The existential is a compiler-generated box, a kind of type-eraser, that wraps the actual value you pass.

When you add an associated type, this doesn't change. The first is a generic function that will be specialized with the specific type. The second requires an existential.

Swift currently cannot generate an existential for a protocol with an associated type, so the final version won't compile. When Swift can, the feature will be called the "generalized existential" and will likely be spelled:

```
func genericFunc(input: any Receiver)
```

For more on the Swift team's thinking around that future syntax, see [Improving the UI of generics](https://forums.swift.org/t/improving-the-ui-of-generics/22814).

For more details about the existential container see [Understanding Swift Performance](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/416/).